# Square roots of Complex Number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Calculate, in the form $a+ib$, where $a,b\in \Bbb R$, the square roots of $16-30i$.

---

My attempt with $(a+ib)^2 =16-30i$ makes me get $a^2+b^2=16$ and $2ab=−30$. Is this correct?

Comment: You realize that the square root is multi-valued, do you not?

Comment: Solve : $(a+ib)^2 = 16 -30i$.

Comment: My attempt makes me get $a^2+b^2=16$ and $2ab=-30$. Is this correct?

Comment: You could also look up DeMoivre's theorem.

Comment: @Mathxx I provided an answer using transformation to polar coordinates.  Please let me know how I can improve this answer;  as always, I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 8):

I'll give steps. You want $(a+bi)^2 = 16-30i$. Expanding and comparing, you get: $$\begin{cases} a^2-b^2 = 16 \\ 2ab = -30\end{cases}$$

Solve for $b$ in the second equation. Substitute in the first one. You have a second degree equation on $a^2$. Use the quadratic formula to solve for $a^2$. Throw away one of the answers bearing in mind that $a,b \in \Bbb R$. Find two values for $a$. For each one you have a corresponding value of $b$. End.

Comment: Why I got $a^2+b^2=16$ instead of $a^2-b^2=16$

Comment: $$(a+bi)^2 = a^2+2abi+(bi)^2 = a^2+2abi+b^2i^2 = a^2+2abi-b^2$$

Comment: You can also multiply the first equation by $4a^2$ to obtain $4a^4-(2ab)^2=64a^2$ - and then you have a direct substitution. This is a technique I learned on this site, which seems to lead to simpler manipulations than other approaches. Here it introduces a factor $4$ which can be cancelled, but is otherwise unproblematic. Of course the factor $2$ could be cancelled from the second equation - then just multiply the first by $a^2$.

Comment: @Mark This is nice. I'll start doing it this way from now on :)

Comment: "first equation" $\: \mapsto \:$ "second equation" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Yes sir! My bad. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to polar coordinates and write $16-i30=\sqrt{16^2+30^2}e^{-i\arctan(30/16)+2n\pi}$.  Upon taking a square root, we find that

$$(16-i30)^{1/2}=(16^2+30^2)^{1/4}e^{-i\frac12 \arctan(30/16)+n\pi}$$

Then, to convert back to Cartesian form, we have

$$(16-i30)^{1/2}=(16^2+30^2)^{1/4}\left(\cos(\frac12 \arctan(30/16)+n\pi)+i\sin(\frac12 \arctan(30/16)+n\pi)\right)$$

Comment: Can you provide more detail for this? How to get $e^{-i\arctan(30/16)+2n\pi}$ ?

Comment: Sure.  No problem.  Euler's identity is $e^{iz}=\cos z+i \sin z$.  So, upon converting to polar coordinates $x=\rho \cos \theta$ and $y=\rho \sin \theta$.  This implies that $z=x+iy=\rho \cos \theta + i\rho \sin \theta=\rho e^{i\theta}$, where $\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$.

Comment: Only two values for $n$ suffice, the rest are just repeats. Also, if you want you can further simplify using known identities for $\sin(\arctan(\cdots$, etc.